# Absolute value of an RBF distance is less than the absolute value of an actual distance

Tags: geometry, 3d, surfaces, interpolation, radial-basis-functions

I have a radial basis function with a linear kernel $f(r)=r$ in $3D.$ I constructed the surface based on this RBF and noticed that the absolute value of actual distance from any point to the constructed surface is always greater than the absolute value that is returned for this point by RBF. Can this fact be proved?

Comment: 1) How do you define and calculate the distance from a point to the surface? 2) Is your surface defined as  $\{x:\varphi(x)=0\}$?

Comment: @rych I constructed a polygon mesh from the RBF using Marching Cubes algorithm, then took random points and for each of them compared the value returned by RBF with the distance to the nearest triangle. Yes, surface is defined as {x:φ(x)=0}.